# Unity build process doesn't include audio files

Tags: unity-game-engine

I'm running into an issue where making a standalone build in Unity is causing the audio files to not be copied over (from what I can tell) or built into the "App_Data/unity default resources" file.  If I hand copy paste the audio files into the builds resources folder, the build works fine.  My files are .ogg's, they are stored in the Assets/Resources folder with all the images that are built in with the build.  The ogg files do appear in Unity and I reference them in my C# script.  Audio works when running in Unity itself and after copying over the audio assets into the standalone builds directory.

Please note that I'm hoping that the build process itself can do this rather than having to write a post-build script to copy the data.  Writing this script would be no problem, but I'm a bit surprised that Unity didn't do it automatically.

Does anyone know why Unity isn't copying them over?  Is there a setting that with all my searching I still haven't found?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are your audio files tagged as "_editor only_"? See [this question](http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/381087/everything-on-resources-folder-goes-to-the-build.html)...

Comment: When I build a player for target iOS, even files that are definitely not used at all are considered. I think they will are bundled in _Data/resources.assets_ (for iOS). As stated from user2599140 you should check the editor log.

Comment: Are the assets immediate children of a directory named "Resources", or are they in a subdirectory?

Comment: jahroy:  It appears GameObjects are the only things that can be tagged as "editor only", audio files don't have tags.

Kay:  I would love to see this happen!  From the post jahroy pointed me to it should include my audio assets by default, even if unreferenced in the editor...  :(  I am however seeing references to my audio files inside of Data/resources.assets.  Did they get packed into here and if so, why can't I load them?  I'm loading with WWW.

rutter:  My directory structure is:
- Assets/Resources/Audio/.  It has oggs along with a couple subdirectories for additional oggs.  None load.

Answer (score 2):

Unity is very good at including just what you reference in the editor. If you don't reference your ogg files in the editor, Unity can't serialise the reference and won't be able to figure out that you need it in the project, just because you reference it in code.

If you have a game object in the editor that has an audio source, and you put of of your ogg files in it (in the sound clip field), that audio file is going to get included in the project. Any other type of editor reference will make Unity include a file in the project.

If you're using sound files by loading them dynamically, then you need to include all your sound files in Assets/Resources and the load them with Resources.Load().

Finally, to check exactly which files are being included, you can check the editor log. If Unity isn't copying the files in the Resources folder, then the only possible answer is that you send a bug report to them, via Help->Report a Bug in the Unity Editor.

Comment: While this does appear to allow the audio file to be known by Unity, it is only allowing me to specify a single audio file.  Will I have to write a script that has an array of audio files that I can drag and drop mine into?  This seems like a design Unity wouldn't go for.

I load the files via www as I was unable to get Resources.Load() to work with the audio files (but it does work with everything else I load).

I'm unable to find this log file.  It appears it should be in my appdata/temp/... folder, but it's empty.  Where can I find this?

Thanks for the tips!

Comment: You could have an object with an array of AudioClip and drag all your sound files there, but using resource.load is much more scalable. In my code I have:

Comment: You could have an object with an array of AudioClip and drag all your sound files there, but using resource.load is much more scalable. In my code I have:

    (AudioClip)Resources.Load(AudioFilename, typeof(AudioClip)); 

The AudioFilename string is the path to the sound, starting from Resources i.e. if you have a folder called Sounds where all your sounds are, the AudioFilename would be Sounds/sound1.ogg .

I load different sound files depending on the build and it works just fine. All my sounds are inside Resources/Sounds and Unity copies them.

Comment: Log files are here: http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/Manual/LogFiles.html

After you build your app, you'll be able to see which files got included and their since in the bundle.