# Unity 3D, WWW function works in the editor yet when I build to PC the audio files are not loading or playing

Tags: audio, unity-game-engine, runtime

Yeh I know the function works fine in the editor but when I build to PC no luck in getting the audio imported. The Audio source and listener are loaded in another class at runtime. This works perfectly when running it in the editor but when i build the game to PC no luck when trying to play audio at runtime.

```
# void Start()
    {
        if (aSource == null && aListener == null)
        {
            //creating the audio sources for the music to play
            //and audio listener in order to hear the music
            aSource = gameObject.AddComponent<AudioSource>();
            aListener = gameObject.AddComponent<AudioListener>();
            toggleBrowser = false;
        }
        // Getting the component play Button
        playButton = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("PlayButton");
        button = playButton.GetComponent<Button>();

    }

    public void toggleFileBroswer()
    {
        // Toggle the file browser window
        toggleBrowser = !toggleBrowser;
    }

    public void OnGUI()
    {

        // File browser, cancel returns to menu and select chooses music file to load
        if (toggleBrowser)
        {
            if (fb.draw())
            {
                if (fb.outputFile == null)
                {
                    Application.LoadLevel("_WaveRider_Menu");
                    toggleBrowser = !toggleBrowser;
                }
                else
                {
                    Debug.Log("Ouput File = \"" + fb.outputFile.ToString() + "\"");
                    // Taking the selected file and assigning it a string
                    userAudio = fb.outputFile.ToString();
                    //Starting the load process for the file
                    StartCoroutine(LoadFilePC(userAudio));
                    toggleBrowser = false;
                    startLoad = true;
                }

            }
        }
    }

    void Update()
    {
        // Making the play button inactive untill the file has loaded
        if (startLoad)
        {
            loadTime += Time.deltaTime;
        }

        if (loadTime >= 5)
        {
            button.interactable = true;
        }
    }

    public void playTrack()
    {
        // Dont destroy these GameObjects as we load the next scene
        Object.DontDestroyOnLoad(aSource);
        Object.DontDestroyOnLoad(aListener);
        //assigns the clip to the audio source and play it
        aSource.clip = aClip;
        aSource.Play();
        Debug.Log("Playing track");
    }

    IEnumerator LoadFilePC(string filePath)
    {
        filePath = userAudio;

        print("loading " + filePath);
        //Loading the string file from the File browser
        WWW www = new WWW("file:///" + filePath);

        //create audio clip from the www
        aClip = www.GetAudioClip(false);

        while (!aClip.isReadyToPlay)
        {
            yield return www;
        }           
    }

    public void exit()
    {
        // Exit game, only works on built .exe not in the editor window
        Application.Quit();
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you provide some code please? Your question is very vague.

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19533434/unity-build-process-doesnt-include-audio-files

Comment: This doesn't help as I cant predict what audio files the user will be importing as it will be from their music collection